# Warning when open hyperlinks from SharePoint Excel documents

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, excel-services, office-2016

I uploaded excel spreadsheets that contain hyperlinks to other Excel files to a SharePoint document library. When I opened the hyperlinks in the external storage, everything is working fine. However, when I opened Excel files and clicked on hyperlinks from SharePoint I received that warning, I should click on OK to open the links.
I want to remove it, I tried some solutions related to security but it didn't work. Is it related to SharePoint? Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: version of sharepoint and office?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 and office 2016

Answer (score 3):

It is not SharePoint issue rather it is Office problem. You can disable this warning going by going to trust center settings of excel.

- Click the File tab.
- Click Options.
- Click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings.
- In the Trust Center, click Macro Settings.
- Make the selections that you want.
- Click OK.

Read more here: [Change macro settings in the Trust Center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6#__toc311698312)

Another helpful link to understand it. [Virus warning appears when you click hyperlink to program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183923)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me .